# data sorting in nodejs isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm working on a sliders which is showing data from the backend. Using the "status: 1, dueDate: 1 " function. It is showing in reverse order, But I need it to show these slides according to status that first show "pending(btn-success)" and then "completed(btn-warning)"

NOTE: slider has also (pending "btn-danger") in it which has to shown first), it has no status

Firstly show (btn-danger), after it show status = pending (btn-success), and then status = completed (btn-warning).

screenshot of slider:  https://ibb.co/jJqLbQQ

controller code:

```
  var renderListOfMeetings = async function(req, res) {
try {
  checkRoles(req);
  let meetings = await Meeting.find({}).sort({ status: 1, date: 1 });
  let tasks = await Task.find({}).sort({ status: 1, dueDate: 1 });

  res.render("meeting", {
    title: "Meetings",
    pdfUrl: config.pdfUrl,
    isAdmin: req.roleAdmin,
    sectionBCommittee: [],
    meetings: meetings,
    tasks: tasks
  });
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex.message);
}
```

};

front-end code:

```
  function setTasksCarausel() {
    html = '<div class="carousel-inner no-padding">';
    let tasksCopy = utils.setSliders(Array.from(tasks));
    tasksCopy.map((tasks, index) => {
        html += `<div class="item ${index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}">`;
        tasks.map(t => {
            html += `
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pending-task-btn" onclick="handleClickTaskItem('${t._id}')">
                    <span href="" class="btn ${t.status === 'completed' ? 'btn-warning' : (new Date(t.dueDate) < new Date() ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-success')} btn-lg dashboard-icon" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                        <p style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">${t.type}</p>
                        <p style="padding-top: 12px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">${utils.convertDate(t.dueDate)}</p>
                        <p style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">( ${t.status } )</p>
                    </span>
                </div>
            `;
        });
        html += `</div>`;
    })


  function setMeetingCarausel() {
    let meetingsCopy = utils.setSliders(Array.from(meetings));

    let html = '<div class="carousel-inner no-padding">';

    meetingsCopy.map((meeting, index) => {
        html += `<div class="item ${index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}">`;
        meeting.map(m => {
            let className = m.status === 'completed' ? 'btn btn-warning btn-lg dashboard-icon' : 'btn btn-success btn-lg dashboard-icon'
            html += `
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" onclick="handleClickMeetingItem('${m._id}')">
                    <span href="" class="${className}" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                    <p style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold;">${m.subject}</p>
                    <p style="padding-top: 12px; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold;">${utils.convertDate(m.date)}</p>
                    <p style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold;">( ${m.status} )</p>
                    </span>
                </div>
            `;
        });
        html += `</div>`;
    })
```

complete screenshot: https://ibb.co/SKVh4Jp

Comment: can you show the code for Meeting.find({}).sort({ status: 1, date: 1 }) ?

Comment: @mosmk  there are the two sliders task and meeting let me show code and view, note: the task slider has btn-danger in it the meeting has not

Comment: @mosmk check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

```
 let meetings = await Meeting.find({}).sort({ status: 1, date: -1 });
 let tasks = await Task.find({}).sort({ status: 1, dueDate: -1 });
```

Please try Above

Use the **-1** for the latest documents.

Comment: result: https://ibb.co/0jgYTcq nthing changed just btn-danger goes at end which has to show first

Comment: check the code again its arranged according to status first and then date